# Multithread instance of mysql error

Tags: java, mysql

I have an web app that use multithread process and each process open an connection with MYSQL like this this code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + SQL.host + "/" + SQL.database + "?user=" + SQL.username + "&password=" + SQL.password);
```

We set in mysql max-connection=10000.

Somes times we received this errors for each multithread process:

> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:341)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor147.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>   MySQL.SQL.(SQL.java:37)
>   SMS.ProccessSMSMessages.processMessage(ProccessSMSMessages.java:26)
>   SMS.StaticData$1.OnWorker(StaticData.java:93)
>   Utility.TimerWorker$1.run(TimerWorker.java:58)
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) Communications link failure
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

Comment: Unless you post more info: exception class, etc, I would think the server is down or a network failure. It states that the driver HAS NOT received packets from the server.

Comment: Andreas please the link that you offer as duplicate NOT have a solution.

Comment: Hello, efektive, When the app start works fine with mysql. but when the app received around 50 concurrent open connection failded.

Comment: That may be the case but the bottom of the exception is clear: driver is waiting for server. If all of the connections are experiencing the same then server is down or there is a network failure.